# Largest consecutive integers with no prime factors except $2$, $3$ or $5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The number $180$ has a special property. Its prime factors are only $2$, $3$, and $5$. However the number $220$ does not have this special property because one of its prime factors is $11$.

In the first one-hundred natural numbers, the numbers with this property are plentiful. They cover almost half of that range. However, into the thousands, or tens of thousands, they get increasingly rare, and you might go hundreds of integers without finding one. As far as I know, $80$ and $81$ are the two largest consecutive numbers that both have this property — $80 = 2^4 \times 5$ and $81 = 3^4$. I have tested numbers up to one million, and have not found another pair of numbers like this.

But, is it possible to *mathematically prove* this? Has anyone ever tried to do it before? All evidence points to the fact that $80$ and $81$ are the largest pair of integers with this property, but has it ever been proven before?

Comment: I am sure D.H. Lehmer & Co. did some work on the matter. Now I just need to find the papers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Størmer%27s_theorem provides an algorithm to solve your exact problem. According to that method, $(80,81)$ is indeed the largest.

Comment: The Wikipedia link gives a link to the relevant work of Lehmer, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067456

Answer (score 12):

Only one of the two consecutive numbers can be divisible by $2$. Similarly, only one is divisible by $3$ and only one is divisible by $5$. Depending on how we pair the prime powers we therefore have six possibilities.

**The cases $p^Aq^B=r^C-1$ can all be solved in the same way.**

> $2^A3^B=5^C-1 $

If $A\ge4$ then modulo $16$ we have $C\equiv 0\pmod 4$ and then $5^C-1$ has a factor of $13$.

If $B\ge2$ then modulo $9$ we have $C\equiv 0\pmod 6$ and then $5^C-1$ has a factor of $31$.

The remaining values of $A,B$ give the solutions $\{4,5\},\{24,25\}$.

> $2^A5^B=3^C-1 $

If $A\ge5$ then modulo $32$ we have $C\equiv 0\pmod 8$ and then $3^C-1$ has a factor of $41$.

If $B\ge2$ then modulo $25$ we have $C\equiv 0\pmod {20}$ and then $3^C-1$ has a factor of $11$.

The remaining values of $A,B$ give the solutions $\{2,3\},\{8,9\},\{80,81\}$.

> $3^A5^B=2^C-1 $

If $A\ge2$ then modulo $9$ we have $C\equiv 0\pmod 6$ and then $2^C-1$ has a factor of $7$.

If $B\ge2$ then modulo $25$ we have $C\equiv 0\pmod {20}$ and then $2^C-1$ has a factor of $31$.

The remaining values of $A,B$ give the solutions $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{15,16\}$.

**The cases $p^Aq^B=r^C+1$.**

> $2^A\times3^B=5^C+ 1$

Modulo $4$ we have $2^A\times3^B\equiv 2\pmod 4$. Therefore $A=1$ and $2\times3^B=5^C+ 1.$

If $B\ge2$ then modulo $9$ we have $C\equiv 3\pmod {6}$ and then $5^C+1$ has a factor of $7$.

The remaining values of $B$ give the solution $\{5,6\}$.

> $2^A\times 5^B=3^C+ 1$

Modulo $4$ we have $2^A\times3^B\equiv 2\pmod 4$. Therefore $A=1$ and $2\times5^B=3^C+ 1.$

If $A\ge3$ then modulo $8$ we have $3^C\equiv -1\pmod {8}$ which is impossible.

If $B\ge2$ then modulo $25$ we have $C\equiv 10\pmod {20}$ and then $3^C+1$ has a factor of $1181$.

The remaining values of $A,B$ give the new solution $\{9,10\}$.

> $3^A\times 5^B=2^C+ 1$

The cases $AB=0$ have been covered in previous equations. So we can suppose $AB>0$ when the equation is impossible modulo $15$.

Comment: I think it's good to note that the cases are not mutually exclusive. It doesn't affect this particular proof, but it's good to be in the habit of considering whether one's cases are mutually exclusive so that one does not forget to do so in a case where it does matter. Also, I think it would be good to clearly give the largest pair.

Comment: Yes. I've now used the overlap of cases in the treatment of equations 5 & 6.

Comment: Can this rule be applied to more prime factors? Say, 2, 3, 5, and 7. The highest pair like this I can think of off of the top of my head is 2400 and 2401, but is there a higher one?

Comment: I guess that it can be applied. However the number of cases starts becoming prohibitive. As it was it took me several hours to do and neaten up the six cases above (although I'd be a lot faster now!)

Comment: On reflection if you were keen on tackling this (and are good at programming) then I guess the way forward would be to set up a computer program which could test a large range of moduli -  especially powers of 2,3,5,7. That would probably leave a more manageable set of 'difficult' cases to do by hand.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think the cases where there's a single prime on one side would be that much more difficult than those above. That would leave 12 cases  (there are 6 ways to pair up the primes and then there's a choice of which side for the '1'.) Interesting but challenging!

Comment: For the record: the largest 2 consecutive 7-smooth integers are $4374=2\cdot 3^7$ and $4375=5^4\cdot 7$. An application of the ratio of these integers to music tempereament is the [ragisma](https://en.xen.wiki/w/4375/4374).